# Prolog append list in a list

Tags: list, prolog, append

I have a list of lists, I want to append more lists to it.

Suppose I have a list:

```
L=[[A,B],[C,D]]
```

I want to append a list

```
L1 = [E,F]
```

to it, how should this be done? 'append' would just put it as:

```
[[A,B],[C,D],E,F]
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
appendlist(New, Old, [New|Old]).
```

but it puts the new list before the old one, I want to reverse the order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a too much synthetic answer, but here it is:

```
?- append([[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]],L).
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].
```

Comment: you are right, just need to put an extra set of square brackets around the list